# Tool to delete files and skip files which are in use (Windows XP)?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, file-management

Using Windows XP. File Explorer stops deleting files when it hits a file which is use. Is there a way to make it skip all files which are in use and just delete the others? 
If you will recommend a file explorer alternative, please mention the free one(s).

Comment: may be xcopy can help in moving files to the NUL device. Didn't try it myself but if you look at all the comandline parameters...

Comment: You cannot *move* files with xcopy, only copy.

Answer (score 1):

Try total commander, I know it's not free, but you get a 30 day trial.

When deleting, if you hit files that are in use it offers you a choice of skipping that one or skipping all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `del` command in regular Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`), it skips all locked/in-use files and deletes all the available files.

Comment: How do you get delete subfolders with it?

Comment: `del` removes files only, you can use `/s` parameter to remove files from subdirectories (all directories remain). Command `rmdir /s <path>` removes folder specified with <path>, all it's subfolders *and* all files in them.